Idiomatic alternative to “going to Canossa”
The metaphorical expression to go to Canossa means:

To humble oneself, as in “he went to Canossa when he reversed his policy”.

The saying refers to an event that happened nearly a thousand years ago:


A reference to Canossa Castle in Emilia Romagna, Italy, where Emperor
Henry IV humbled himself before Pope Gregory VII in 1077 to have his
excommunication lifted.


This expression, though present in main dictionaries, appears to have first become popular around the time of the American Civil War in the middle of the Nineteenth Century but has become less and less common since then according to
Google books.

Is there a more contemporary and common alternative idiomatic expression to go to Canossa for present-day English?
[The phrase's popularity had nothing to do with the American civil war or America. It was due to a speech by German Chancellor Otto von Bismarck on 14 May 1872 in which he said "we shall not go to Canossa".]

"bending to somebody's will" (to do what someone else wants, especially when you do not want to) is an alternative, but not really an idiom, because its meaning is quite deductible from those of the individual words.

@Graffito Would bending the knee or kissing the ring count as idioms?

Slightly off-topic: the sudden rise in the popularity of the phrase around 1870 was presumably triggered by German chancellor Bismarck's famous use of it in an 1872 speech, in the context of a dispute between the German government and the Catholic Church. I can't find any uses of "Canossa" as a general metaphor for accepting defeat in the English-language Google corpus prior to that (the only hits are literal accounts of the 1077 historical event).

@tchrist  I have trouble bending my knees because of my rheumatism problem, therefore I can't kiss your ring.

related: to kowtow

@tchrist:  "Kissing the ring" even has the same connotations of humbling oneself before a religious authority.

Both kiss the ring and bend the knee have lately been used for people who embrace a certain controversial and narcissistic public figure after criticizing him.

Where are those quotes from?

To eat humble pie:

The idiom eat humble pie means to face humiliation and subsequently apologize for a serious mistake.

or eat crow:

a colloquial idiom, used in some English-speaking countries, that means humiliation by admitting having been proven wrong after taking a strong position
…
Eating crow is of a family of idioms having to do with eating and being proven incorrect, such as to "eat dirt", to "eat your hat" (or shoe), or to put one's foot in mouth; all probably originating from "to eat one's words", which first appears in print in 1571 in one of John Calvin's tracts on Psalm 62: "God eateth not his words when he hath once spoken".


Merriam-Webster identifies "eat crow" as US English; I'm not sure where the OP is.

@StuartF: To my ear (as a Brit who lived some years in the states), “eat crow” may well be a bit less common in British English than American, but it’s not markedly American in the same way that, say, “sidewalk” is — certainly not unnatural or jarring in a British English context.

I've never encountered He went to Canossa, and (relatively speaking) nor has Google NGrams.
If "being humbled" is a defeat, He met his Waterloo, as per my linked chart. If not, just say He had to eat humble pie.


https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-to-canossa 2) https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+to+Canossa 3) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Canossa#:~:text=%3A%20a%20place%20or%20occasion%20of,when%20he%20reversed%20his%20policy


...and lest you tell me it wasn't a fair comparison, since my above chart doesn't include a subject in met his Waterloo, here's another chart, including the pronoun subject - and also showing prevalence for the truly idiomatic to be sent to Coventry.

I've altered 'idiomatic' (which does unhelpfully have the non-default sense 'relating yo idioms') to 'metaphorical' in line 1.

One of the very few instances I found that are not historical in nature: … adding that he did, however, call on the Interstate Commerce Commission, which was "a pretty prompt going to Canossa… (1966) The ngram chart you posted is misleading, "he went to Canossa" vs "met his Waterloo" it doesn't mean the two are synonymous. I'll admit that the majority of results for "go/ going/ went/ to Canossa" I perused through, referred to historical events.

-1 Google ngrams has encountered "going to Canossa" and "the American people are not going to Canossa for their educational models, neither are they going to Paris." in these examples, would "met his/their Waterloo" fit.

errata corrige: "met his (etc.) Waterloo" would not fit.

@Mari-LouA: Obviously the OP has found instances of go[ing] to Canossa in Google Books -  I was simply using the search for OP's own text He went to Canossa to show that it has next no currency. It's irrelevant that it's still in dictionaries if almost no-one uses it today. Hence the "meaning" will be potentially uncertain for both speaker/writer and audience/readers. Only precise context tells us whether "humbling oneself" represents a "defeat" OR an admission of past errors - perhaps in the context of "self-improvement" (personal gain). If the former, Waterloo works fine.

"if no one uses it today" That's precisely why the OP is asking for an updated version, and Waterloo isn't the best equivalent, if at all. I'm not totally convinced either that "eating humble pie" matches the examples I cited earlier but I can't think of anything better. Maybe "cap in hand"?

To go cap in hand means to beg for favour, which would hardly be relevant to the OP's context of a person in authority reversing a policy. I don't understand your rejection of either of my offerings, but you've said your piece and cast your vote, so let's just leave it there.

The answer is in the question: humble oneself.

humble oneself idiom 
: to do or say something which shows that one knows one has been wrong, has behaved with too much pride, etc.  
He needs to humble himself and ask for their forgiveness.
Merriam-Webster


First, a bit of history. There were two ways this phrase has been used. Prior to German Chancellor Otto von Bismark's speech on 14 May 1872, it mostly appeared in histories and moral stories, and the event  was often described as the emperor humbling himself to the pope. This was, quite simply, propaganda. It completely ignores the political reality that it was either do that or be deposed by an insurrection supported by the pope. The story had been spun to be an example of the virtue of humility.
Bismarck had no such illusions, and ever since 1872, the phrase has focused on the coercive use of power and the humiliation of being forced to grovel at the feet of another. Bismarck said "we shall not go to Canossa, either in body or in spirt." This is what spurred the resurgence of the phrase.
As an alternative, there is

It's your day in the barrel.

This is the punchline of a well known dirty joke. But the idiom has escaped and is used by people who have no idea where it came from.
See in particular note 4 excerpted from the Wikipedia article below.

Safire, William (2002 March 31) “On Language”, in The New York Times Magazine‎[4], “… I had written that it was somebody’s “turn in the barrel,” forgetting that the phrase originated in the punch line of a dirty joke. I apologize for blanking out on that; the phrase seems to have crossed into general usage from its sexual origin, …”

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_barrel
Nevertheless some will undoubtedly consider it cringy.

What exactly do you mean by cringy here? How would you express this without using that word?

How about inherently cringeworthy. Its a pretty common word nowadays and in all the dictionaries. The spelling hasn't been settled yet. - cringey/cringy.

Do you mean that it's embarrassing?

Yes, either directly; or it makes you feel uncomfortable because you think it may embarrass others.

The saying/punchline in this answer seems to be unrelated to the idea of formally humbling oneself before someone of higher status, and is rather the conclusion of what would fill many with horror.

@Greybeard In the OP's example of reversing policy, there is nothing humbling about that. You will be put through the wringer by friend and foe alike. If you look up "road to Canossa",  you'll find it defined in terms of penance and submission, not humility. Wikipedia says it often implies coercion. The usual thought is that it is a public demonstration of power over another for propaganda purposes. The other name for it is "humiliation at Canossa".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_to_Canossa#:~:text=In%20modern%20usage%2C%20%22going%20to,act%20of%20penance%20or%20submission.
